# pageshow vs pagecontainershow in jQuery mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm in the process of updating my jQuery Mobile site to 1.4.2.

When I change this:

```
$(document).delegate('#locations', 'pageshow', LocationsPageShown);
```

to this:

```
$('#locations').on('pagecontainershow', LocationsPageShown);
```

it no longer fires the event. FWIW, this fires the event:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', LocationsPageShown);
```

But of course, I need it to fire when the locations page is shown, not just a generic document selector.

--- Edit 1 ---

This works:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#locations', LocationsPageShown);
```

But this doesn't:

> $('body').on('pagecontainershow', '#locations', LocationsPageShown);

Comment: Oh, it might be because I'm getting there using $.mobile.changePage('#locations'); instead of $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#locations');

Comment: No, I don't think that was it...

Comment: New page containers can't be delegated https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7283

Comment: How utilize pageContainer events http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Answer (score 2):

The selector for pagecontainershow should be :mobile-pagecontainer. If that does not work for you, you can use $("body") as in 1.4 the body is always the page container:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
  alert( "This page was just hidden: " + ui.prevPage );
  alert( "The current page is : $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ));
});
```

The second parameter of the event (ui in the example above) gives you the page you are coming from.  To get the current page you can use `$(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" )`.

So you can look at the current page ID to decide what code should be run.

Comment: Just use $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(event, ui) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [here jqm doc](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/):

> In jQuery Mobile 1.4.0, the two events are identical except for their name and the fact that pagecontainershow is triggered on the pagecontainer, whereas pageshow is triggered on the page.

So the main difference is the fact that `pagecontainershow` is received by the page container while `pageshow` is received directly from a page. From `pagecontainershow` you can get the destination page as `ui.toPage` and its `id` is `ui.toPage[0].id`

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) {
    // Refer page as ui.toPage or ui.toPage[0].id
    ...
});
```